# Access AWStats information from PHP?

Tags: php, logging, traffic, awstats

Would it be possible to access the visitor county origin information from AwStats using PHP? A new feature I would like to add to a project lists the countries of of recent visitors (30 days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is find the country from the IP address in the Apache access log.  This is the same log Awstats uses to generate its data.

1. Use a class such as
   [the one created by Eric Lamb](http://blog.ericlamb.net/2010/01/parse-apache-log-files-with-php/)
   to parse the Apache access log.
2. In the same script, use a
   service like [hostip](http://www.hostip.info/use.html) to determine the
   country.
3. Create a cron job to run the script every night at
   2AM.